# Angular 7 and HTML selects issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular 7 reactive form which have, among others, the following fields:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-2">
    <select formControlName="network_interface" (change)="onInterfaceChange($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let ifc of interfaces; let idx = index;" [value]="ifc.id">
            {{ ifc.id }} - {{ ifc.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-col-2">
    <select formControlName="interface_ip">
        <option *ngFor="let obj of interfacesIps; let idx = index;" [value]="obj.id">
            {{ obj.name }}&nbsp;({{obj.address}})
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Basically, it allows the user to select an interface and interface IP from 2 lists, stored in the arrays `interfaces` and `interfacesIps`.

One combo is 'tied' to the other, so if I select an interface the other combo must show its internal IP addresses. This is done in the `onInterfaceChange` event handler, fired by the `change` event. This is what I do:

```
onInterfaceChange(interfaceId : any): void {
    // NOTE: this.interfaces[INDEX].ips is an array of IP addresses
    this.interfacesIps = this.interfaces[interfaceId].ips;
}
```

This works, and the IP list is refreshed whenever I change the selected interface, BUT I've realized that the form control associated to the combo (`interface_ip`) is not updated. It should be the first IP in the list, but I keeps the old value, until I change to another IP.

I've fixed this by manually changing the form control value on the event handler above, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it automatically.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you provide a StackBlitz example? Correct me if i'am wrong, are you trying to implement a dependent dropdown?

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's exactly what I want, a master-slave behaviour, the values of one dropdown depend on the other's. I'll try to set up an Stackblitz demo when I have a minute.

Comment: I wrote a possible solution, in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can subscribe to the `network_interface` form control value change as follows;

```
this.network_interface.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
// your code here
});
```

you may also want to change `[value]` to `[ngValue]` if you're working with non string values

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change `[value]` to `[ngValue]` inside option tag.

Select tag doesn't have any value but option tag does have.so if you want to bind option's value in select tag, you need to use angular's `SelectControlValueAccessor` which basically bind the option's value to select tag.

You can use `SelectControlValueAccessor` by using `ngValue` inside option tag.

You need to change your code as following:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-2">
    <select formControlName="network_interface" (change)="onInterfaceChange($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let ifc of interfaces; let idx = index;" [ngValue]="ifc.id">
            {{ ifc.id }} - {{ ifc.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-col-2">
    <select formControlName="interface_ip">
        <option *ngFor="let obj of interfacesIps; let idx = index;" [ngValue]="obj.id">
            {{ obj.name }}&nbsp;({{obj.address}})
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you need a dependend dropdown, you just need to populate the first with the data as you already did, to populate the second you need to use a propriety of reactive form called valueChanges, it's listen for changes of that formControl.

```
this.network_interface.valueChanges.subscribe((selectedValue) => {
    /* 
     Here you select wich data to put in other select based on selectedValue
    */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions! This is what I've done:

I've changed the `[value]` for `[ngValue]`. Now, the `change` event on the dropdown isn't fired anymore, so I used the `valueChanges` observable on the network interfaces form control to load the appropriate addresses when it changes:

```
this.formModel.controls['network_interface'].valueChanges((value) => {
  // Update the addresses on interface change
  this.interfacesIps = this.interfaces[value].ips;
});
```

Now all works as expected.

Thanks everyone!